# Spring boot application main, not recognized in jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Here is my plugin:

[image]

Error when running jar:

[image]

I maven clean > maven package... to build the jar

Any idea where I have gone wrong? Thank you

Comment: looks like your jar does not contain Application class.
Try executing `jar tvf jarname`

Comment: Why are you using both the assembly plugin and Spring Boot's Maven plugin? What sort of jar are you trying to build?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I am new too this, which one should I remove?

Comment: @GnanaJeyam What does this command do?

Comment: I would remove the assembly plugin. You can use https://start.spring.io to generate a Spring Boot project that uses Maven with the recommended configuration.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Ok I was following a guide to create the jar, and added that plugin. I will try removing it

Comment: @AndyWilkinson My jar now found the Application class, my system is running. However this jar file is not named 'with-dependencies' does this matter?

Comment: @Josh  Using that command u can list out the files in the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andy Wilkinson
"I would remove the assembly plugin. You can use start.spring.io to generate a Spring Boot project that uses Maven with the recommended configuration."

I did this, and the JAR now finds the main class